# Modeling rare events

Tags: regression, logistic, resampling, fraud-detection

I am looking to model fraudulent cases using logistic regression. However there are tow different datasets which are available.

1. I used to build my model on; it had 4% of fraud cases. My model on this gave me a pretty good accuracy.
2. The dataset on which to validate the model. The problem being that this dataset contains on .02% of fraud cases and this leads to a drastic fall in the model accuracy.

Do I need to resample in order to tackle this problem? Or is there any other way?

It would be really great if a research paper is provided for reference.

Thanks

Comment: How large are the datasets? 0.02% of 5,000,000 is a lot harder to deal with than 0.02% of 5,000,000.

Could the different percentages of cases indicate differences in setting/assessment of fraud etc. so that a model developed for one setting may not necessarily be good for the other?

How did you build the original model? If you did e.g. naive stepwise regression or picked any predictors that appeared to have a naive unadjusted p<0.05, then it is entirely plausible that you would have a seemingly great model on the first dataset (due to overfitting) that will not do well on a new dataset.

Comment: @Björn its .02% of 900,000. The first dataset was 1 million rows. I did go for a naive bayes. What is the way out that u suggest?

Comment: That sounds like you have a lot of data for your model development, but how many potential variables for your model did you have? In the two digits? Or way more? And again, is there a logical reason for the very different percentages that might suggest why no model might transfer from one setting to the other? Random forests are a logical alternative that I might have considered.

Comment: Fraud is 200 times as common in one dataset as in the other.  With the 2nd, 180 cases of fraud is not terrific, not terrible as a basis for modeling, logistic or otherwise, but as @Bjorn said, you should account for any differences between the two databases if you want training-set modeling to be validly tested by validation-set results.

Comment: How are you measuring model accuracy? What is the projected usage of your model? Do you include interactions in your model? These are more important questions than percentages of fraud in your data.